# how to print right angle triangle having combination of integers without using python str() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Expected output is as follows:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

The following code that gives me desired output

```
def generate_palindromic_triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        line = ""
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            line += str(j)
        for j in range(i - 1, 0, -1):
            line += str(j)
        print(line)

# Example usage
generate_palindromic_triangle(5) have to complete the code using exactly one print statement.
```

But my requirement has the following constraints:

- Need to use only integers
- Must be having a linear time complexity or less
- Mustn't use more than 1 `print` statement

Comment: Are you allowed to use recursion?

Comment: I think the purpose of the exercise is to get you to think about how to create a single number for each line with the digits you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursion and unpacking to replace for loops:

```
def f(n, x=1):
    if x > n:
        return
    for i in (*range(1, x), *range(x, 0, -1), '\n'):
        print(i, end='')
    f(n, x+1)

f(5)
```

Variant without for loop:

```
def f(n, x=1):
    if x > n:
        return
    print(*range(1, x), *range(x, 0, -1), sep='')
    f(n, x+1)
```

Output:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the pattern carefully, each line is a square of numbers having all 1s

For example.

1. 1*1 = 1
2. 11*11 = 121
3. 111*111 = 12321
   and so on.

Therefore, you can do it like this.

```
def generate_palindromic_triangle(n):
    number = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        number = (number * 10) + 1
        print(number**2)

# Example usage
generate_palindromic_triangle(5)
```

Output:

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

The only constraint is, it'll print perfect palindromic strings only up to 10 terms.

Comment: That does require the length of the pyramid being less than 10, but it is by far the simplest solution. However, the answer _does_ involve strings, so I would just keep track of a number which gets multiplied by 10 and adds 1 to do the calculation.

Comment: Right @BRemmelzwaal, but there must be constraints to the problem as well since the condition is to do it using only 1 loop, i.e. with a linear time complexity, but to reverse the string or a number makes it quadratic.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal it's unclear what the pattern should be if you went to 10 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list(range(n)) to build the lists and then unpack them into the print statement:

```
def generate_palindromic_triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        line = list(range(1, i)) + list(range(i, 0, -1))
        print(*line, sep = "")

generate_palindromic_triangle(5)
```

Output:

```
1  
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Answer (score 1):

One call to print(), no calls to str()

```
def gpt(n):
    x = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        yield (x := x * 10 + 1) * x

print(*gpt(5), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you posed this question, one answer is:

```
print('1\n121\n12321\n1234321\n123454321\n')
```

Comment: Well, if you take the constraints to the letter, I totally agree with you :) Is this a legal loophole ?

Comment: The question sounds a bit like an homework assignment to me... so if this will do the job, everyone in the class learns something about proper definitions ;)

Comment: Indeed; I now see `use only integers` which is more to the point than `don't use str()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way:

```py
def generate_palindromic_triangle(n):
    prev = ""
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(prev, i, prev[::-1], sep="")
        prev = f"{prev}{i}"
# Example usage
generate_palindromic_triangle(5)
```

**Output**

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this solution is of quadratic complexity.

Comment: I am wondering, if this kind of solution is correct. You don't use `str()` but in fact, you are using a formatted string...